# how to pull out a commit from git history?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-revert

I've confused how to fix my problem. 
My git history is like this (commit id):

```
commit: f8ae2 -> parent: 71bf9 
commit: 71bf9 -> parent: f67c0 
commit: f67c0 -> parent: 5b18a 
commit: 5b18a -> parent: 9e111 
commit: 9e111 -> parent: ce53b
commit: ce53b -> parents: f1b1a, 2055e
commit: f1b1a -> parent: 2055e
commit: 2055e
```

Since I'm the only person who works on a branch - and still not merged in upstream - I want to pull out or remove `commit: f1b1a` from history. Therefore, I want `commit: ce53b` has only `2055e` as its parent.

What should I do? Any suggestion would be appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an interactive rebase for this: run

```
git rebase -i --onto 2055e 2055e
```

then delete each line you don't want to have in your history.

Comment: I found cherry-pick is also interesting. http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/03/04/pick-out-individual-commits.html

Comment: @Hesam cherry-pick would get the commit to another branch .. but will that work out in this case ?

Comment: @VinayVeluri, I tested cherrey-pick first but yup you are right, it didn't help me and then used Nils suggestion. VIP opened and I deleted the line that I wanted. Nils suggestion is the answer.